# Fixed Table Size

Tags: php, html

```
foreach($model as $person)
{

        if($n % 3 == 0)
            $html = $html .'<tr>';

        $html = $html . '<td width="95px" style="text-align:center">'. student photo.'</td>';  

        $html = $html . '<td width="80px">'.name.'</td>';

        if(($n+1) % 3 == 0)
            $html = $html . '</tr>';

            $n++;
}

$html = $html . '</table>';
echo $html;
```

I want to display 3 sets of student pic + name in each row. It display nicely as how i want it to be.However, when i display only 1 or 2 records,the data are not fixed. * I want it to be same size/position as the 3sets data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell what styles you may have applied to the table, but this is what I think is going on: The cells are likely changing position because when you only have 1 or 2 entries, the table is only 2 or 4 cells wide, unlike when you have 3+ entries, where the table is always 6 cells wide.

Since you're using percentage-based widths for your name cells, you'll get weird effects as the name cells try to compute how wide they should be. Try using pixel-widths for the name cells, padding the table with a blank cell, or setting the width of the table?

**What I see  going on:**

```html
<h3> 3 Cells </h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="95px" style="text-align:center">Photo</td><td width="23%">First and last name</td>
    <td width="95px" style="text-align:center">Photo</td><td width="23%">First and last name</td>
    <td width="95px" style="text-align:center">Photo</td><td width="23%">First and last name</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/><br/>
<h3> 2 Cells </h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="95px" style="text-align:center">Photo</td><td width="23%">First and last name</td>
    <td width="95px" style="text-align:center">Photo</td><td width="23%">First and last name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**The simplest solution to your problem**
Insert pairs of blank cells matching the width of the cells that would be there if you were to have a full row of pictures.

```html
<h3> 3 Cells </h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="95px" style="text-align:center">Photo</td><td width="23%">First and last name</td>
    <td width="95px" style="text-align:center">Photo</td><td width="23%">First and last name</td>
    <td width="95px" style="text-align:center">Photo</td><td width="23%">First and last name</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/><br/>
<h3> 2 Cells </h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="95px" style="text-align:center">Photo</td><td width="23%">First and last name</td>
    <td width="95px" style="text-align:center">Photo</td><td width="23%">First and last name</td>
    <td width="95px"></td><td width="23%"></td> <!-- See this pair of spacers -->
  </tr>
</table>

<br/><br/>
<h3> 1 Cell </h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="95px" style="text-align:center">Photo</td><td width="23%">First and last name</td>
    <td width="95px"></td><td width="23%"></td> <!-- See this pair of spacers -->
    <td width="95px"></td><td width="23%"></td> <!-- See this pair of spacers -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Assuming "n" is scoped outside of the loop, you could very simply do this with an extra bit of code similar to this: (I don't have php handy to check it)

```
foreach($model as $person)
{

        if($n % 3 == 0)
            $html = $html .'<tr>';

        $html = $html . '<td width="95px" style="text-align:center">'. student photo.'</td>';  

        $html = $html . '<td width="23%">'.name.'</td>';

        if(($n+1) % 3 == 0)
            $html = $html . '</tr>';

        $n++;
}
$temp_n = n
while($temp_n % 3 !=0){
        $html = $html . '<td width="95px" ></td><td width="23%"></td>';
        if(($temp_n+1) % 3 == 0)
            $html = $html . '</tr>';
        $temp_n++;
}


$html = $html . '</table>';
echo $html;
```

**A prettier solution:**

```css
.fixedtable{ width:100%}

.profile{
  width: 33%;
  background-color:#eee;
}

.profile .photo,
.profile .info{
  display:block;
  float:left;
}

.profile .info {padding:4px}

.clear{clear:both}
```

```html
<h3> 3 Cells </h3>
<table class="fixedtable" cols="3">
  <tr>
    <td class="profile">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/95x96" class="photo"><div class="info">First and last name</div><span class="clear"></span>
    </td>
    <td class="profile">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/95x96" class="photo"><div class="info">First and last name<br/> More information</div><span class="clear"></span>
    </td>
    <td class="profile">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/95x96" class="photo"><div class="info">First and last name</div><span class="clear"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/><br/>
<h3> 2 Cells </h3>
<table class="fixedtable" cols="3">
  <tr>
    <td class="profile">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/95x96" class="photo"><div class="info">First and last name</div><span class="clear"></span>
    </td>
    <td class="profile">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/95x96" class="photo"><div class="info">First and last name</div><span class="clear"></span>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</table>
```

Comment: I did try setting the width of the table to pixel ,however same result applies

Comment: Try the sample php I just added--it's the closest way to your original design that i can think of while still having it work :) I don;t have a php interpreter handy, so you might have to fiddle with it a little in case I got the numbers off.